# Automatically install package dependencies with terminal

Tags: software-installation, deb

I have a .deb file in my downloads folder than i need to install with a bunch of dependencies.  What is a command that will install the package with the dependencies.

I know this is probably a duplicate but i just want the command to install the package from the downloads folder and automaticly install dependencies, because i don't know much about the terminal

Answer (score 1):

The command you are probably looking for is `gdebi`. It should be provided by the `gdebi-core` package.

```
GDEBI(1)                                                              GDEBI(1)

NAME
       gdebi - Simple tool to install deb files

SYNOPSIS
       gdebi [package.deb]...

DESCRIPTION
       gdebi  lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing its
       dependencies. apt does the  same,  but  only  for  remote  (http,  ftp)
       located packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

first run *sudo dpkg -i downloaded_package.deb*

You will probably get errors about missing packages (dependencies) now. Execute:

*sudo apt-get -f install*

Comment: i ran that with the name of the file and got this isaac@isaac-Latitude-D830:~$ sudo dpkg -i wine1.6-i386_1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing wine1.6-i386_1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine1.6-i386_1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1_i386.deb

Comment: try 2nd command now

Comment: isaac@isaac-Latitude-D830:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
then a bunch of file names     Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: The first command returned an error saying the deb file wasn't found, so nothing was installed. Make sure you are in the right directory.